# RollbackException in a UserDetailsService implementation and Cannot commit JPA transaction (Hibernate)

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have been stuck on this problem for a while and I need your help. I will try to give as much details and will edit as needed.

I'm trying to create user in database in my custom UserDetailsService from Spring security. 
the scenario is : When a user logs in my application, I check my database if the user exists; if not, I call a webservice to check if this user exists and import all his information in order to save them to my own database and grant him the access to the web application.

I can read information from the database (SELECT queries) but I cannot do any insert without getting the following (beautiful) error:

```
org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationServiceException: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction
org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:85)
```

In other part of the application (once authentified) I can use any services from controllers. Insert + select work fine.

About my configuration, I have the following files:
spring security config (Spring security context) is in "applicationContext-security.xml" 
spring beans (Root Context) in "applicationContext.xml"
spring mvc (DispatcherServlet) in webmvc-config.xml
and a applicationContext-jpa.xml + persistence.xml

implementation of UserDetailsService:

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {


    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    [...Other Declarations...]

    @Autowired
    private userService userService;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String login) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = null; //extends spring security UserDetails 

            //If I try to find existing users in database here, it works perfectly
        User user = userService.findUserByLogin(login);

        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = ...
        Set<String> permissions = ...

        if(user == null){
             //Call webservice and get User if exists => newUser

           //Save in user table
                userService.saveUser(newUser);  
               //No error here, I can even try a userService.findUser(newUser.getId()); and I get the results. the commit is after returning the UserDetails from this method.


             //I also tried the following solution... the entitymanager is well Autowired and I can access everything as usual
           //   em.getTransaction().begin();  // => Throw here 'nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to create transaction on shared EntityManager - use Spring transactions or EJB CMT instead'
           //   em.persist(operator); 
           //   em.getTransaction().commit();
           //   em.close();
                    user = newUser

            }
            else{
                      //Other things
            }

        }
        return user;  //if I tried a saveUser, commit is done after the return and the exception is thrown
    }
}
```

I tried all combination of @Transactional on class and method itself.

and now all the config files [only the useful parts of the config files]

web.xml:

```
 <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath*:META-INF/spring/applicationContext*.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <listener>
     <listener-class>org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <listener>
     <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>myApp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>WEB-INF/spring/webmvc-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
```

applicationContext.xml :

```
<context:spring-configured/>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.company.myApp">
    <context:exclude-filter expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" type="annotation"/>
</context:component-scan>


<bean class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close" id="dataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driverClassName}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${database.url}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${database.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${database.password}"/>
    <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true"/>
    <property name="testOnReturn" value="true"/>
    <property name="testWhileIdle" value="true"/>
    <property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="1800000"/>
    <property name="numTestsPerEvictionRun" value="3"/>
    <property name="minEvictableIdleTimeMillis" value="1800000"/>
    <property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1 FROM DUAL"/>
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" id="transactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj" transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" id="entityManagerFactory">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="persistenceUnit"/>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
```

my transaction manager is in mode="aspectj" (I tried without it, proxy)
I have all Aspectj libraries working perfectly. Load-time weaving and whatnot. 
I also use *.aj files in my application. 
I also tried to add a aop:advisor on my customUserDetailsService class

applicationContext-security.xml :

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" 
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd" profile="local,dev,int">
    <global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled">
        <expression-handler ref="expressionHandler"/>
    </global-method-security>
    <!-- HTTP security configurations -->
    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
        <expression-handler ref="webExpressionHandler"/>
        <form-login login-processing-url="/resources/j_spring_security_check" login-page="/login" authentication-failure-url="/login?login_error=t" />
        <logout logout-url="/resources/j_spring_security_logout" />
        <!-- Configure these elements to secure URIs in your application -->
        <intercept-url pattern="/resources/**" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/login/**" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
        <session-management session-fixation-protection="migrateSession">
            <concurrency-control max-sessions="1"/>
        </session-management>
        <x509 subject-principal-regex="CN=[^,]* ([^,]*),.*$" user-service-ref="customUserDetailsService"  />
        <logout delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" />
    </http>
    <!-- Configure Authentication mechanism -->
    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <!-- SHA-256 values can be produced using 'echo -n your_desired_password | sha256sum' (using normal *nix environments) -->
        <authentication-provider  user-service-ref="customUserDetailsService">
            <password-encoder hash="sha-256" />
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>    
</beans:beans>
```

the applicationContext-jpa.xml has only basic repository declaration :

```
<beans:beans xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd">

      <repositories base-package="com.company.myApp.common.repository" />

</beans>
```

the webmvc-config has the context:component-scan for controllers and other stuff needed only for the webapp.
with `<aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>` and other aop:advisors.

I'm testing on a ApacheTomcat Service embedded in Eclipse STS

EDIT: full stacktrace:

```
Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction
org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:85)
org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java:132)
org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:156)
org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:174)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:94)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:194)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.java:88)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:125)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:173)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:615)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:409)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Comment: Can you provide the full stack trace?  I am thinking that there is an exception happening further down the line that is causing the rollback.

Comment: I added the stacktrace, thank you for your help. I checked in debug mode and there isn't any apparent error (with a try/catch); it did persist in the db (with no commit) and right after I can select it. the code go through the entire method and send the return value. when I hardcode the 'newUser' to bypass the service call (saveUser()), it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a solution... It was a stupid mistake but I was close to the solution. The configuration above is actually good. The RootContext and the SecurityContext are sharing the transactions and the beans.

By calling manually the persist() method from the entity manager WITHOUT beginning a transaction, gave me another stacktrace. The problem was actually a JSR303 validation fail... (Bad RegExp that comes from the webservice)

So for future use, this configuration (in the question) works if you want to share the 'dataSource' to the Spring SecurityContext. 
to have the stacktrace from my problem i used the following:

```
   em.persist(user); 
   em.flush();  
   em.close();
```

Thank you for your help anyway :)